# Qual a melhor maneira de estruturar uma tabela MySQL em árvore?

Tags: mysql, estrutura-de-dados

Qual a melhor maneira de estruturar uma tabela de produtos onde tem categorias e filhos infinitas, como árvore? Para depois conseguir fazer uma pesquisa autocomplete simples? Obrigada

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uma possível forma seria a tabela para categorias (`tb_categorias`) contendo as seguintes colunas:

- idCategoria
- idSubCategoria
- nomecategoria

Se `idSubCategoria = 0`, ela é categoria **Pai**, se for `>= 1` ela é então categoria **Filho**, de acordo com o nome de cada categoria.

E na tabela de produtos:

- idProduto
- idCategoria (onde já tem categoria e subcategoria setada)

Depois só recuperar dados! ;)

Comment: Obrigadaaaaa!!!

Answer (score 0):

**Tatiana**, você pode usar "**Nested Set Model**" pois proporciona consultas muito eficientes onde cada item tem um único pai e zero ou mais filhos.

[Talvez isto](http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/) possa te ajudar.

Comment: Muito obrigada! Achei bem legal e parece ser simples... vou estudar melhor!!!

Comment: @TatianaMartini EU achei complicado! haha mas estamos aí p/ isso! Vote na minha resposta e a ajudou, obrigado.